SwiftUI How can I modify an object from an array and update the corresponding sub view automatically?
import SwiftUI

// MARK: This is just a very simple model
struct Person: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    init(id: Int, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}

// MARK: This is a view model,where I can load data from server or modify an object
class Model: ObservableObject{
    @Published var personList: [Person] = []
    
    // This is a fake function, load data from service
    func loadDataFromServer(){
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+2){
            self.personList.append(contentsOf: [
                Person(id: 1, name: "Davy"),
                Person(id: 2, name: "Bob"),
                Person(id: 3, name: "Nancy")
            ])
                
        }
    }
    
    // I need to modify the object via a network call, And then update view automatically,how can I do that???
    func changeName(person: Person){
        print("start change name")
        // Mimic a netwotk call
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+2){
            // Yeah,changed
            print("change successed")
            // ⚠️⚠️⚠️ How can I change it to a new value and refresh the view?
//            person.name = "A New Name"
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = Model()

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(model.personList) { person in
                Cell(person: person)
            }
        }
        .environmentObject(model)
        .onAppear(perform: {
            model.loadDataFromServer()
        })
    }
}

// MARK: a very simple subview
struct Cell:View {

    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model
    var person:Person

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(person.name)
            Button("Change Name") {
                model.changeName(person: person)
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

Here's what I expected:when I clicked the button【Change Name】 below 【Davy】,【Davy】would change into 【A New Name】;When I clicked the button below 【Bob】,【Bob】 would change into 【A New Name】.
I've tried @Binding、@State、@Observable,etc,but it dose not work,Xcode just keep offering me errors and warnings,I'm so confusing
Is there anyone kind-hearted who can help me
Click to view the image

try this approach using in ContentView
 @StateObject var vm: ViewModel = ViewModel()

and in func changeName(person: Person)
 if let index = self.personList.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == person.id}) {
     self.personList[index].name = "Mickey Mouse"
 }

EDIT-1:
Alternative approach using @Observable class
// MARK: This is just a very simple model
@Observable class Person: Identifiable {  // <--- here
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    init(id: Int, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}

// MARK: This is a view model,where I can load data from server or modify an object
@Observable class ViewModel {  // <--- here
    var personList: [Person] = []  // <--- here
    
    // This is a fake function, load data from service
    func loadDataFromServer(){
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+2){
            self.personList.append(contentsOf: [
                Person(id: 1, name: "Davy"),
                Person(id: 2, name: "Bob"),
                Person(id: 3, name: "Nancy")
            ])
        }
    }
    
    // I need to modify the object via a network call, And then update view automatically,how can I do that???
    func changeName(person: Person) {
        print("start change name")
        // Mimic a netwotk call
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+2){
            // Yeah,changed
            print("change successed")
            // ⚠️⚠️⚠️ How can I change it to a new value and refresh the view?
            person.name = "Mickey Mouse"   // <--- here
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var vm: ViewModel = ViewModel()  // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(vm.personList) { person in
                Cell(person: person)
            }
        }
        .environment(vm) // <--- here
        .onAppear{
            vm.loadDataFromServer()
        }
    }
}

// MARK: a very simple subview
struct Cell:View {
    @Environment(ViewModel.self) var vm: ViewModel  // <--- here
    var person: Person
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(person.name)
            Button("Change Name") {
                vm.changeName(person: person)
            }
        }
    }
}


did my answer not work for you?
